# Method is not returning correct answer?Does anyone have anymore input?

Tags: java

In this method I am supposed to return the winner of the election. This is done by using the `candidatesWithFewest()` method repeatedly until there is only one candidate(which has the most votes). You receive a vote by being the first name on a ballot. If two or more candidates have the same amount of first place votes then the election is not decisive. My error is that when that two or more candidates have the same amount of first place votes it stills return one of those candidates. All my other methods return the correct output so I believe the problem is in the `getWinner` method. 
candidatesWithFewest returns a list of all candidates with fewest votes. i want to remove those candidates from the list until there is only one candidate left.

```
    /**
    * Returns the winner of the election using the candidatesWithFewest()
    * method.If there is no winner method returns a statement stating the
    * election is not decisive.
    *
    * @param vbal VoterBallots object
    * @param candList a list of candidate names
    * @return the winner of the election
    */
    public String getWinner(VoterBallots vbal, ArrayList<String> candList) {
        // Run rounds until down to a single candidate
        while (candList.size() > 2) { 
            ArrayList<String> loser = vbal.candidatesWithFewest(candList);
            String listString = "";

            for (String s : loser) {
                listString += s;
                candList.remove(listString);         
            }          
        }

        if (candList.size() > 0) { 
            return candList.iterator().next(); // Return the surviving candidate
        } else {
            return "Election is non decisive.";
        }
    }

    /**
    * Returns a list of one or more candidates tied with the fewest
    * first choice votes
    *
    * Precondition: each String in candidateList appears exactly once
    * in each Ballot in ballotList
    *
    * @param candidateList a list of candidate names
    *
    * @return a list of those candidates tied with the fewest first
    * choice votes
    */
    public ArrayList<String> candidatesWithFewest(ArrayList<String> candidateList) {
        ArrayList<String> losers = new ArrayList<String>(); //empty list for losers
        int minTally = ballotList.size() + 1;      //number of min votes
        for (int can = 0; can < candidateList.size(); can++) {
            String candidate = candidateList.get(can);
            // // number of first place votes
            int votes = numFirstVotes(candidate, candidateList);
            if (votes < minTally) {
                minTally = votes;
                losers = new ArrayList<String>(); // adds loser to list
            }
            if (votes == minTally) {
                losers.add(candidateList.get(can)); //adds losers with the same vote
            }
        }
        return losers;  // returns list of candidates with fewest votes
    }
   /**
     * Returns the number of times a given candidate appears first, among those
     * elements that are on candidateList, among all elements of ballotList
     * (i.e., among all ballots)
     *
     * @param candidate the name of a candidate
     * @param candidateList a list of candidate names Precondition: candidate
     * appears in candidateList
     * @return the number of times that candidate is first among those in
     * candidateList for all elements of ballotList
     */
    public int numFirstVotes(String candidate, ArrayList<String> candidateList) 
        // implementation not shown
        {
            int numVotes = 0;
            for (Ballot voterBallot : ballotList) {
                String first = voterBallot.firstChoiceFrom(candidateList);
                if (candidate.equals(first)) {
                    numVotes++;
                }
            }
            return numVotes;
    }
    /**
     * @param candidateList a list of candidate names
     * @return the name of the first choice candidate for this Ballot from those
     * in candidateList
     */
        public String firstChoiceFrom(ArrayList<String> candidateList) {

        for (String firstChoice : ballot) {
           if(candidateList.contains(firstChoice))
           {
           return firstChoice;
           }          

    }
        return null; // does not appear on candidate list
}
}
```

Comment: Is more detail needed?

Comment: you probably just want `candList.remove(s)`  I think because you keep appending the losers onto the `listString` that probably is not the name of the loser you want to remove, it would be all the names and thus the `candList.remove` would fail

Comment: Shouldn't `candList.remove(listString);` be `candList.remove(s);`?

Comment: `losers = new ArrayList<String>(); // adds loser to list` Code doesn't match comment, are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: If I do candList.remove(s) I always get "Election is not decisive".

Comment: @Name that is because `candidatesWithFewest` is returning all the names which actually is because your logic in the if statements is very off.

Comment: candidatesWithFewest returns a list of all the candidates with the fewest votes. That could be 0,1,2 and etc.

Comment: @Name when you say "fewest" do you mean the one(s) with the _least_ amount of votes, or just _all except_ the one with the _highest_?

Comment: The one with the fewest. I want to keep calling the candidatesWithFewest method until there is only one candidate left. in which that candidate has the most votes.

Comment: @Name what happens in a tie?  Or what _should_ happen?

Comment: @chancea Then i want to return a statement saying that the election is not decisive.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of removing losers iteratively, why don't you just select winners in one shot? That wouldn't require that `while` loop at all.

Comment: @Name I just ran this code (using a mock method for `numFirstVotes`) and using `candList.remove(s)` and I got the proper output.  Can we see the data you are using and the `numFirstVotes` method?

Comment: Are you somewhere playing with the `candidateList` list? Your code seems fine to me at least.

Comment: Here I mocked it up on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/uM6oza) using just simple characters.  It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try with `candList.remove(s);`  instead of `candList.remove(listString);`

Also, actually as per me, there are some issues in this method

```
public ArrayList<String> candidatesWithFewest(ArrayList<String> candidateList) {
    ArrayList<String> losers = new ArrayList<String>(); //empty list for losers
    int minTally = ballotList.size() + 1;      
    for (int can = 0; can < candidateList.size(); can++) {
        String candidate = candidateList.get(can);
        // // number of first place votes
        int votes = numFirstVotes(candidate, candidateList);
        if (votes < minTally) {
            minTally = votes; //.... here you have made minTally == votes
            losers = new ArrayList<String>(); // adds loser to list ..... here again you are repeating the first line of this method
        }
        if (votes == minTally) { //..... this will be true because although originally votes were less than minTally still, your assignment makes them equal
            losers.add(candidateList.get(can)); //adds losers with the same vote
        }
    }
    return losers;  // returns list of candidates with fewest votes
}
```

Comment: If I do that I always get "Election is not decisive"

Comment: in that case, please have a look at the method that returns losers......

when you have to remove a candidate, you should just remove that candidate and not add it into a list and remove everything

Comment: The thing is that the method that returns losers returns a list. And I have to extract each string from the loser list and remove it.

Comment: please check my answer... have made some edits.
Also, i know that it returns a list, but you are using a foreach loop. So all the elements of that list will be fetched and you can remove them one by one..... try using pen and paper with a dummy sample. You will understand I am sure

Comment: the line if(votes == minTally) is only true when the preceding if statement is executed. There is a chance that the preceding if statement could be skipped but this one could still be executed. It all depends on the data and how numFirstVotes works.

Comment: @Hardy
i agree with you. I just wrote those because it doesnt seems right. So i just pointed it out so that he can have a relook if he actually wanted to code it that way.

Comment: I added the other methods

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code snippet :

```
for (String s : loser) {
            listString += s;
            candList.remove(listString);         
        }
```

is creating the problem for you, because it will work fine for first run only; for the rest (n-1) runs it will not remove anything!

I can't understand that why you are joining the candidate names into listString variable?
If you need to remove a single candidate name then following should be correct way:

```
for (String s : loser) {
            //listString += s;
            candList.remove(s);         
        }
```

makes sense?

Comment: If I do this I always get "Election is not decisive." I'm not sure why.

Comment: Two things you need to check-
First : check this code snippet :
`code`  
if (votes < minTally) {
            minTally = votes;
            losers = new ArrayList<String>(); // adds loser to list
//Add this candidate in the losres list too
losers.add(candidateList.get(can));
        }

Second:
double check this method **bold** numFirstVotes(candidate, candidateList); whether it is returning the correct thing?

Answer (score 0):

this is a suggestion. If you dont like it, leave it!

A clearer way to solve this kind of problem would be to use a hashmap with 
The candidate name will be the key and the value is the number of votes.
As you iterate through the list of votes, check if the candidate's name exists in the map, if so, simply increment the count, else set it to 1 (which means the first vote you see)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are lots of issues with your code that could be causing problems.

```
for (String s : loser)
{
    listString += s;
    candList.remove(listString);
}
```

This code is appending each name in the loser list and trying to remove it from the candList, so assume the loser list has [joe, john, dave] in it, then that loop is saying remove("joe"), then remove("joejohn") then remove("joejohndave")
Is that really what you want it to do?

```
int votes = numFirstVotes(candidate, candidateList);
```

There could be problems here, since ballotList is global perhaps you are using it correctly in this function but since I can't see the code I don't know.

Since we don't have the code for numFirstVotes or how the ballotList is setup it's hard to agree with you that that code works. Your comments don't reflect what the code is doing and should be removed or updated.

I think the real problem is here

```
while (candList.size() > 2)
```

This says, loop until there are 2 or fewer items in the list. It does not say loop until there are 1 or fewer items in the list which based on your comments is what you want it to do.
So, without the rest of your code to test my guess against I can't be sure but I think you want to change your loop condition to

```
while (candList.size() >= 1)
```

If it's still not working after that change then you probably have more problems in your code, like the for loop above and in the numFirstVotes method.

Comment: I think my problem is the example you use used with joe john and dave. Is there a way to separate each name and remove them.

Comment: I am pretty sure if anything it would be `> 1` not `>= 1`

Comment: @chancea do you know how to separate the names joe john and dave like he showed in the example and remove each of those name from the list.

Comment: @Name that is what we were saying with the `candList.Remove(s)`

Comment: I know i tried candList.remove(s). And each time it gives me election is not decisive. Could there be a problem with my if else statement.

Comment: @chancea I think you are right, the >= would make it keep looping until there were none. >1 would be do what his comments suggest.

Comment: Loop condition seems fine. Should be `> 2` only and not `>= 1`. For the latter case, it will make the list to size `0`, if at the end, we're left with 2 minimum elements.

Comment: @Name, if using candList.remove(s) makes it always say the election is not decisive, then you have a bug(s) elsewhere in your code. Post the numFirstVotes function and maybe we can help more.

Comment: @Hardy I added the other methods

Comment: @Name, I don't think firstChoiceFrom works. It currently says get an item from ballot, see if it exists in candidateList and return it if it does, if it doesn't then get the next thing in ballot and see if it exists in candidateList. So that function currently is seeing if anything in ballot exists in candidateList. Based on the comment it should only be checking the first thing in ballot, not everything. You need to get rid of the for loop and (assuming ballot is a list) call something like ballot.get(0) (Again a guess since I don't know what ballot is)

Comment: @Hardy My first choice method works correctly. I tested it and always gave me the correct output. I don't think that will help me in my error for the getWinner method.

Comment: @Name, I forgot your precondition says condidateList will have the same values as ballot, which makes me wonder why you have it at all.  If you want to send me your project I would be happy to run it and see if I have any other ideas for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70169/discussion-between-hardy-and-name).

Answer (score 0):

I would do minor modification to your code. Instead of returning the losers and removing them iteratively, you can directly return the winners from that method. Basically you're finding the max element, by removing min element on each iteration. That is not how you should approach.

Change `candidatesWithFewest` method `candidatesWithHighest`, and change the logic accordingly:

```
public ArrayList<String> candidatesWithHighest(ArrayList<String> candidateList) {
    ArrayList<String> winners = new ArrayList<String>(); //empty list for losers
    int maxTally = ballotList.size() + 1;      //number of min votes
    for (int can = 0; can < candidateList.size(); can++) {
        String candidate = candidateList.get(can);
        // // number of first place votes
        int votes = numFirstVotes(candidate, candidateList);
        if (votes > maxTally) {
            maxTally = votes;
            winners = new ArrayList<String>(); // Reset the list
        } else if (votes == maxTally) {
            winners.add(candidateList.get(can)); //adds winners with the same vote
        }
    }
    return winners;  // returns list of candidates with highest votes
}
```

And then your first method will not require any `while` loop at all. Just get the list, check the size. If it is greater than 1, then throw your error:

```
public String getWinner(VoterBallots vbal, ArrayList<String> candList) {
    ArrayList<String> winners = vbal.candidatesWithHighest(candList);

    if (candList.size() < 2) { 
        return candList.iterator().next(); // Return the surviving candidate
    } else {
        return "Election is non decisive.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. And yeah I like your way better. But i have to use the candidatesWithFewest method.

Comment: @Name That's strange. In that case, your code seems fine to me. Either you're doing something else somewhere, which we don't know. Can you post your `numFirstVotes` method?